# Subclass simple UIButton to checkbox

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uikit

i am subclassing `UIButton` to create a simple Checkbox behavior. here is the code :

```
#import "RadioButton.h"

@implementation RadioButton
@synthesize isSelected;

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[self ChangeButtonState];
 }

  -(void)ChangeButtonState{
  if (!isSelected) {
    isSelected = YES;
    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn_on.png"]      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
    isSelected = NO;
    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }
     }

    -(id)init{
     self.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=YES;
    self.alpha = 1;
     [self ChangeButtonState];
    isSelected = NO;
    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
return self;
    }

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
     {

    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    isSelected = NO;
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code
     }
     return self;
      }

    /*
  // Only  override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
   // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
     - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
       // Drawing code
     }
     */

     @end
```

first, when i set the class in the interface builder to a button when i launch the app i dont see anything until i hit this invisible button.

the seconed thing is the images looks dark then the original

help would be great!
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try your stuff in - (void)awakeFromNib. define this method in your subclass. When you assign your custom class in xib then this method will be called and apply your logic there.

Comment: the first issue is now ok, the image loaded ok before pressing, when i press the button it becomes and stay darker.

Comment: you are doing wrong thing in - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
     {

    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiobtn_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    isSelected = NO;
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code
     }
     return self;
      } always you have to do your stuff after initialising self bcz it may return nil.

Comment: got it 
the code moved to the awake from nib. but this "darken" still happen

Comment: sure, it looks more like the highlighted thing

Comment: use setImage instead setBackgroundImage: bcz it will stretched your image